# AttributeError: logger in P4 script

Tags: python, perforce

I have a simple script that connects to Perforce through Python API and print the connection info.

```
from P4 import P4, P4Exception
p4 = P4()
p4.port = "111"
p4.user = "xxx"
p4.client = "yyy"
p4.connect()
print p4
print p4.run("info") # here is where I get an error
```

I get this error:
`AttributeError: logger` . Here's the traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p4try.py", line 17, in <module>
    print p4.run("info")
  File "C:\..\p4python\dist\p4python-2014.2.962887\P4.py
", line 582, in run
    if self.logger:
  File "C:\..\p4python\dist\p4python-2014.2.962887\P4.py
", line 516, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: logger
Press any key to continue
```

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

logger isn't define at this moment. Look at the Perforce documentation if you don't forget to call some init method. If not, contact the developer to declare a bug, and in the meanwhile, you can patch it with a line like:

```
...
p4.connect()
p4.logger = False # patch the problem
print p4
...
```

Comment: It says `"AttributeError: no integer attribute with name logger"` in the line `p4.logger = False`